# ColdFusion route redirects

Tags: redirect, routes, coldfusion

Is there a way using ColdFusion to have a one page that can route url redirects? I have a bunch of one off page redirects and it is really weighting down my Git commands.

So Like:

abc/index

test/index

redirect/index

etc...

So I'm trying to figure out a way to move these all to one app that can route them to the correct redirect. Doing this on the server is not an option for me as our server admin has a lockdown on access.

Answer (score 2):

the best is to have URL rewrites at the server level.

However, you can you use **onRequestStart** function in your Application.cfc and match the page being called and redirect accordingly.

Basically, have some logic added in the onRequestStart according to your needs.